# Preprocess form data asynchronously in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

One of my form fields is address. Before sending it to the server I want to transform it to latitude and longitude. This requires sending asynchronous request to some external service (e.g. Google Maps API). What's the proper way to do this?

My geocoding snippet:

```
function geocodeAddress() {
  var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
  geocoder.geocode({"address": address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat()
      document.getElementById("latitude").value = lat
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

I see several options:

1. Use `onsubmit` event handler - first return false (to wait for geocoding to complete), then in a separate callback set `latitude` field and submit form.
2. Use `onchange` event handler for `address` field - this requires blocking submit button until we geocode the address; it's also tricky if we prepopulate form values after submit it (e.g. filter rows)

Obviously I can also parse it on the server side, but this may result in one user using all my "quota" in the external service and I'd have to implement some kind of fairness, which I'd like to avoid.

So what's the proper way to solve this kind of pre-processing of form values in javascript?

Comment: Do it on submit - use the callback from the geocode response then manually submit the form (IMO).

Answer (score 0):

You could consider the following approach:

- prevent default behavior of button via [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)
- resolve address via  `google.maps.Geocoder.geocoder` function
- once the address is resolved resume form submit: [`form.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit)

**Example**

```
function saveData(e) {
    e.preventDefault();   //1.stop default behaviour of button
    var address = document.getElementById("txtAddress").value;  
    resolveAddress(address,
        function(results) {
            document.getElementById("txtLat").value = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            document.getElementById("txtLng").value = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0].submit(); //2.resume form submit
        },
        function(status) {
            console.log('An error occured while resolving an address');
        });
}

function resolveAddress(address,success,error) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ "address": address }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            success(results);
        } else {
            error(status);
        }
    });
}
```

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/BJx7TfodwWgpPKbWYUNH?p=preview)